# how to route different version of service registered in eureka

Tags: routes, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

i have various service(all of them registered in eureka server with eureka.instance.metadataMap.versions=v1) runnig now I want to run newer versions of these service(registered with eureka with different version eureka.instance.metadataMap.versions=v2).

now how do i route to these versions by giving version in request url?